# JUnit5 repository class test cases

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

**This my JUni5 repository levele test cases**

```
@DataJpaTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
class WalletRepositoryTest {
    @Mock private WalletRepository walletRepository;
    @Mock private UserRepository userRepository;
    private static final User USER = createUser();
    private static final WalletDetail WALLET_DETAIL = createWalletDetail(USER);

    private static User createUser() {
        final var user = new User();
        user.setUserId(1);
        user.setUid("4dcd810b-b9b1-4006-89a2-b50e9ed5ee67");
        user.setName("guest");
        user.setMobileNo("1234567890");
        user.setEmail("guest98787@guest.com");
        user.setPassword("1234abc");
        return user;
    }

    private static WalletDetail createWalletDetail(final User user) {
        final var walletDetail = new WalletDetail();
        walletDetail.setWalletId(1);
        walletDetail.setUid("86bd3f49-f9bc-425c-b5a1-2f353e9061ff");
        walletDetail.setUser(user);
        walletDetail.setWalletAmount(20.0);
        return walletDetail;
    }
    @Test
    void findByUser() {
        when(userRepository.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(USER);
        when(walletRepository.save(any(WalletDetail.class))).thenReturn(WALLET_DETAIL);
        when(walletRepository.findByUser(anyInt())).thenReturn(WALLET_DETAIL);

        userRepository.save(USER);
        walletRepository.save(WALLET_DETAIL);

        final var result = walletRepository.findByUser(1);

        assertNotNull(result);
        assertEquals(1, result.getWalletId());
    }
}
```

in my project, I am using Gradle
And using PostgreSQL database

when in my system closes the database connection my test cases not working when I create a build.

**show this error**

```
WalletRepositoryTest > findByUser() FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:142
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762
            Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException at JdbcUtils.java:60
                Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException at ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:342
                    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException at Net.java:-2
```

**So my question is when do we really need a database connection for test cases?**

and how do we write JUnit 5 test cases without a database connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an in-memory database if you want to avoid mocking the repository. This will give you more flexibility (for instance, the test will not care if you call `saveWallet` 3 times or `saveAllWallets(...)` once). On the other hand, the mocks will make the test run much faster, so it's basically a trade-off.

In your case, you have to decide if you want to use a `@DataJpaTest` and the in-memory database. This will mean you need to set up the DB connection as explained [in this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database). To test, you will then use @Autowire for the repositories instead of trying to mock them.

Alternatively, you can use `@Mock` or `@MockBean` for the repositories and do not set up an in-memory DB (and no longer user `@DataJpaTest`).

Lastly, you should avoid mocking the class you want to test. So, if you want to test a WalletService that uses WaleltRepo, you can mock WalletRepo. But if you want to test WalletRepo that talks to the DB, you'll need to "mock" the DB by providing this in-memory solution

Comment: my question is do we really need a database connection for test cases?

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is when do we really need a database connection for
> test cases?

This depends on the type of test that you are writing, normally when you are testing something in your application that crosses a boundary to an external system/database, you write integration tests. In this case, by connecting to a database integration tests are more suitable since you are making sure that fetching/saving data is being done correctly.

In this case, you would actually need a `test` database which can be achieved in 2 ways:

1. H2 in-memory database (you need to add the dependency, and configure it ...)
2. Test Containers (you can spin up in docker container the same database technology you are using but for testing)

> how do we write JUnit 5 test cases without a database connection

Then you would need to run Unit Tests, instead of Integration test, which is what you are doing here. In a unit test, you would `mock` your services, whereas, in an Integration Test, you will boot up your spring application and use the actual injected services. To make your tests work in this you would need to avoid loading your application context this could be done by simply removing `@DataJpaTest` and `AutoConfigureTestDatabase` because these annotations are basically telling your test that you are writing an integration test meaning you will actually run you spring boot application and load its context.

In general, it's a better practice to be writing an Integration Test, and remove the `mock` annotation on your repository to actually using an inject service